# Add/complete fixed number of columns on dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm processing multiple R files some have 3 columns

```
id v_1 v_2 V_3
 1 1   2   3
```

Other have more some less

```
id v_1 v_2
 1 1  7
```

Is is possible to "force" every file to have 10 columns (not counting id col) and the extra ones with no values such that you get

For the first example

```
id v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4 v_5 v_6 v_7 v_8 v_9 v_10
1  1   2   3
```

And for the second example

```
id v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4 v_5 v_6 v_7 v_8 v_9 v_10
1  1  7
```

So basically regardless of the number of columns from the input file you always get 10 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `bind_rows`, where you first create an empty dataframe with the desired columns, then bind them together.

```
library(dplyr)

df_cols <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 11, nrow = 0)), c("id", paste0("v_", 1:10)))

bind_rows(df_cols, df)
```

Another (probably faster option) is to use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(list(df_cols, df), fill = TRUE)
```

Another option is to use `plyr`:

```
plyr::rbind.fill(df_cols, df)
```

**Output**

```
  id v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4 v_5 v_6 v_7 v_8 v_9 v_10
1  1   1   2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
```

If you have a list of dataframes, then you could use `map` to update all the dataframes in the list:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(list(df, df2), bind_rows, df_cols)

#[[1]]
#  id v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4 v_5 v_6 v_7 v_8 v_9 v_10
#1  1   1   2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA

#[[2]]
#  id v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4 v_5 v_6 v_7 v_8 v_9 v_10
#1  1   1   2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "id v_1 v_2 v_3
 1 1   2   3", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "id v_1 v_2
 1 1   2", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems effective for small dataframes, but if this changes to v_100 (100 values is not practical)

Comment: @EGM8686 I changed out how the empty dataframe is created, so that it could be updated for any number of columns. As obviously you wouldn't want to type out to 100!